# SQL selecting specific DISTINCT rows

Tags: sql

I'm trying to extract some data were the Event column is distinct but I specifically want only rows that contain the highest number from the Value column, I'm thinking it's some mis-mash of using DISTINCT and GROUP BY but my sql knowledge is limited at the moment, any help would be great

[image]

Comment: What server software are you using?  The best way to do this is different in SQL Server ,Oracle, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Why no Event B rows?

Comment: I just forgot to include it in the mock-up picture of the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT [EVENT]
  ,MAX([Value]) 
FROM [MyTable] 
GROUP BY [EVENT]
```

Comment: This works, although if I try to include extra columns such as ID in the returned results it errors out

Comment: @DavidMcQillan: if you need more columns, consider Gordon's answer

Comment: What is returned by the following statement: `SELECT ID, [EVENT], MAX([Value]) FROM [My Table] GROUP BY ID,[EVENT]`? It should allow you to also specify ID.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using either a subquery or `row_number()`:

```
select event, value
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by event order by value desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

or:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.value = (select max(t2.value) from mytable t2 where t2.event = t.event);
```

You should be careful about naming columns.  `event` and `value` might be reserved words in some databases.

Comment: Looks like a solution for Microsoft SQL Server. Why doesn't aggregate function (like `MAX`) work in this situation?

Comment: @KirillSlatin: Gordon's answer is ANSI SQL and will work on any DBMS that supports [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/de) - judging by David's comment to dwjv's answer, David needs more than just the `event` column in the result, which this solution would be capable of.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks for the hint about ANSI compatibility. However about this solution I hoped Gordon would give out some secrets about performance or anything of that kind... There must be a reason to make things more complicated...

Comment: @KirillSlatin just my $0.02, I've found using ranking functions better performance-wise than the subquery (on SQL Server)

Comment: @KirillSlatin . . . Because the OP specifically says "I specifically want only rows that contain the highest number from the Value column".  That implies that the OP wants all columns, which is not really possible with a single aggregation (except in the extreme case of there being just one other column).  As a_horse_with_no_name says, this is ANSI standard SQL, supported by all reasonable databases.

Answer (score 1):

How about `SELECT [EVENT], MAX([Value]) FROM [My Table] GROUP BY [EVENT]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track.

`select event, max(value) 
from test
group by event`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer too!